# Log2Console tells me I need .NET framework 2.0 when I have 4.5 Installed

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to install Log2Console, but apparently I require .NET Framework 2.0 even though I already have 4.5 present. Could there be dependencies that 2.0 offers that 4.5 doesn't?

The official documentation wasn't very helpful.

I understand this is very application-specific, but I'm trying to understand the seemingly backward-incompatible nature of the .NET framework here if any.

[image]

Comment: As of Windows 8.1, the OS doesn't ship with older versions of the framework. It has to be installed manually as an optional feature. What OS version is this? For these newer OSes, you cannot use the web installer you have to enable it as a Windows feature. It just sounds like Log2Console is out of date.

Comment: You probably did hit the nail on the head. It's a Win 10 x64 machine. But I guess I'm flawed in the assumption that .NET4.5 = .NET(x<4.5)+ extra

Comment: There were breaking changes made from .NET 2.0 to 4.5; you either need to update your software to work on 4.5 or install 2.0 on all machines you want to run your software on.

Comment: Thanks @mikez and dourhigharch. I installed 3.5 which included 3.0 and 2.5 and now it's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look just install the Framework of 3.5 full, restart and it'll be working because it includes **the previous Dll's versions. with the old structure.**